# DJANGO: Redirection in Multi Step Form 

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a multi step form using model classes:

my view:

```
# this is my tz_create view
def makingx(request):
    try:
        #this is to check if user has filled info already before
        dashprofile =  DashboardProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        #some view stuff
        context = {

        'user':user
         }
        return render_to_response(
        'done.html',
        context,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request),
         )

    except DashboardProfile.DoesNotExist:
        #some more stuff
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                #more view stuff
                request.session['created_busi'] = True

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tx_create'))
        else:
            return render_to_response(
                 'd12.html',
                 {
                  'user':user},

             context_instance = RequestContext(request)
               )
```

my tx_create view:

```
def promocamp(request):
    if 'created_info' not in request.session:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('tz_create')
        )

    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        if campaign.is_valid():
           #some stuff
            if 'next' in request.POST:
                next = request.POST['next']
            else:
                next = reverse('busi_create')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    return render_to_response(
            'd14.html',
            {'CampaignForm':campaign,
            'user':user},

                 context_instance = RequestContext(request)
                   )
```

Step needs to go from tz to tx create
However tx_create never seems to show up... what should i do / what could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I see that `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tx_create'))` is called on three conditions:

1. DashboardProfile.DoesNotExist must be raised
2. Request method must by "POST"
3. form must be valid

Just make sure that all three conditions are met. Use some debugging output in each of these conditions to see where the flow breaks.

Comment: "Use some debugging output" what do you mean?

Comment: Just insert some `print "something"`statements into your code and see if it's printed to the console. Insert these `print`s right after `except` and `if` statements.

Comment: Is there a better method to execute the conditions? as in another way to go about the code?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set `session['created_info']`?

```
if 'created_info' not in request.session...
```

Also, where do you use `request.session['created_busi']`?